# MultiProcessing with ProcessPoolExcecutor gives un expected results

Tags: python, list, while-loop, multiprocessing

Here i my code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class MyProcessPoolExecutor(ProcessPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._running_workers = 0

    def submit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        future = super().submit(*args, **kwargs)
        self._running_workers += 1
        future.add_done_callback(self._worker_is_done)
        return future

    def _worker_is_done(self, future):
        self._running_workers -= 1

    @property
    def pool_usage(self):
        return self._running_workers


my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i = 0


def foo(x):
    global i
    i += 1
    if i <= 10:
        print(x)
        my_list.append(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with MyProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        finished = False
        while not finished:
            while my_list:
                executor.submit(foo, my_list.pop(0))
            finished = (executor.pool_usage == 0 and not my_list)
```

Basicly what I try to achieve is to get the list "my_list" to be printes twice on multiple processes. Problem is my code stops after jut one "iteration" - i tried to add new while statement as shown above but still getting just "1,2,3,4,5" not "1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5" as I'd expect.
Has anyone encountered this problem and can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with two different `my_list`s.

Add this to your program

```
def foo(x):
    print('id of my_list in launched process:', id(my_list))
    global i
    ...
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('id of my_list in main process:', id(my_list))
    with MyProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        ...
```

and run it to see what's happening.

So you don't append anything to `my_list` in the memory space of the "coordinating" process and `finished` is `True` after 5 steps.

Comment: yeah - i tracked the problem to same issue thx, any idea on how can  solve this issue somewhat easily? - I'm not new to python but definately new to multiprocessing. this problems bugs me reall hard

Comment: I'm not sure: Is there a reason why you don't "duplicate" `my_list` before the multiprocessing part? I think that would be the cleanest way.

Comment: in any different problem yes but I really need it to be one list :-) (new items are added/subtracted to/from original list).